# Node/Express Rest API - How to throw an error from mssql

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, rest, express

I'm quite new to both javascript and Node/Express, and it's probably a newbie question, but here goes...

I'm building a Rest API, and want to `throw new Error(err.message)` from this function:

```
function hentForfatter(id, callback) {

        sql.connect(config, function(err) {

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        }

        new sql.Request().query('SELECT * from Forfatter where ForfatterID = ' + id).then(function(recordset) {
            callback(recordset[0]);
        })

        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        });

    });
}
```

... so I can do this in my Express API route:

```
router.get('/:forfatterid/quizer/:quiz_id', function(req, res, next) {

    try {
        db.hentQuiz(1, function(result) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    } 

    catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send(error)
    }

});
```

I can't get my head around how to do this... Anyone that can help? :)

Comment: Please see if [this](http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2013/12/20/using-sql-server-with-nodejs/) is helpful?

Comment: Please let us know wha libraries you are using too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node, there is a convention that the first parameter of a callback should be the potential error.

```
function hentForfatter(id, callback) {

  sql.connect(config, function(err) {

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err); //notice the return statement
    }

    new sql.Request().query('SELECT * from Forfatter where ForfatterID = ' + id).then(function(recordset) {
        callback(null, recordset[0]); //notice I send null for the error
    })

    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    });

  });
}
```

(I'm not sure how you get form `db.hentQuiz` to `hentForfatter`.)

```
router.get('/:forfatterid/quizer/:quiz_id', function(req, res, next) {

  db.hentQuiz(1, function(err, result) {

    if(err) return res.status(404).send(error);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, seems I'll go for your solution using error as a callback parameter instead of the try/catch pattern. Just trying to figure out the "right" way to do error handling in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using two parameters if using callbacks:

```
callback(err, result)
```

And then check for 
`err` and `result`.

In addition look up how promise chains work.